# Linguagem C comando switch 2 instruções dentro da mesma case

Tags: c

Estou com problema em fazer incremento usando o `switch`, por exemplo, quero usado um acelerador e toda vez que chamar a `case '+':` ele faça dois incrementos exemplo:

```
potencia=potencia+10;                
altitude=altitude+1000;
```

Um deles, o segundo esta retornando valores incorretos, fiz o código em javascript, funciona perfeitamente, agora em C não estou conseguindo.

Segue código abaixo e imagem em anexo.

```c
int main(){

int potencia=0;
int altitude=0;
char acelerador;

do{

    printf("\n +Use (+) para aumentar velocidade/ (-) deminuir:");
    gets(&acelerador);

    switch(acelerador){

    case '+': 
            potencia=potencia+10;
            altitude=altitude+1000;
            printf("\n %d",potencia);
            printf("\n %d",altitude);

 }


 }while(acelerador !='s');

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você cometeu um engano com a variável acelerador. Declarou como um char (um único caractere) mas está utilizando a função gets para ler tal variável, contudo a função gets lê uma string ou array de caracteres e ainda acrescenta o terminador '\0'. Pode ser que sua leitura esteja destruindo a área de memória da variável que está com problemas. Usualmente encerramos os comandos de um case com o comando break; caso contrário ele continuará a execução dos comandos a seguir mesmo que pertençam a outro case.

Comment: Rodei seu código sem problemas aqui, os valores saíram corretos. Detalhe, não se esqueça de finalizar um `case` do `switch` com `break`.

Comment: É realmente, rodei em outra plataforma e consistiu o erro, troquei para scanf na leitura do char e rodou tranquilo. @anonimo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomendo que não utilize gets, caso queira pode utilizar fgets no lugar. Porém eu utilizo scanf mesmo.
Troque gets(&acelerador) por:

```
scanf("%c", &acelerador);
```

E tudo funcionara bem.

Código completo com #include  e break no case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int potencia=0;
  int altitude=0;
  char acelerador;

  do{
    printf("\n +Use (+) para aumentar velocidade/ (-) deminuir:");
    scanf("%c", &acelerador);
    switch(acelerador){
      case '+':
              potencia=potencia+10;
              altitude=altitude+1000;
              printf("\n %d",potencia);
              printf("\n %d",altitude);
              break;
   }
   }while(acelerador !='s');
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfeito amigão, perfeitamente agora.